# MQTT Support on IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am trying to get mqtt on edge preview according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11)
I can’t get it to work because using VSC to add **mqttBroker** as a desired property on the manifest fails as below:

```
There are errors in deployment manifest file: 
data.modulesContent.$edgeHub['properties.desired'] should NOT have additional properties
```

Comment: It will be helpful to include more details. The manifest would be a great start.

Comment: the manifest is an exact match to the one in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Since you are following the the How-to guide step by step, please submit a new issue at the bottom of the document with your issue so that we can enhance the document.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the link of the issue so I can follow-up? In the meantime please accept answer in this thread.